# Getting Response Text From Ajax Call

Tags: java, html, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get the response from an Ajax call into a html label. I am using a tomcat server. Ia m able to see the description returned form the server however how do i get the responses into the lable text. Under is what i have tried:

**Jquery**

```
 function GetDescription(Id){                   
        $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'getDescription.htm',
        data:{dId:Id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $('.TypeDesc').text = data.responseText;

        }

    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {      


            $(".photos").each(function(i){              

                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                       var image = new Image();                      
                        image.src =  $(this).val();

                        image.onload = function(){ 
                                       var typeId = document.getElementsByClassName("TypeId")[i].value;
                                       GetDescription(typeId);

                                       var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
                                       ctx.drawImage(image,0,0, 320, 240); 
                         }               
                }
            });       




        });
```

**html**

```
</head>
<body>
<div id ="content">
<c:forEach items="${object}" var="i">
<div id="table">    
    <div>
        <p><canvas class="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>
    </div>
        <a href="registration.htm">Name:- ${i.fName}  ${i.lName}</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="photo" value="${i.photo}" class="photos"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="Number" value="${i.Number}" />
        <input type="text" class="TypeId" value="${i.citizenTypeId}"/>
        <label class="TypeDesc"></label>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this to the parameters of the ajax call

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('.TypeDesc').each(function(){
            $(this).text(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: @ razzak how can i set TypeDesc.text for each item in the class presently its setting the first value for all the TypeDesc

Comment: its still setting all the values of the label to the first value. I need to access the index of the $(this).text

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're telling jQuery you're expecting JSON:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

...and so it's (trying to) parse the response as JSON and pass you an object, but then you're trying to use it like a raw XHR object.

If you want the *text*, remove the `dataType` or change it to `dataType: 'text'`, and then use `data` which will be a string.

Your other problem is that [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) is a *function*, not a property, so you need to *call* it.

So:

```
dataType: 'text',
success: function (data) {

    $('.TypeDesc').text(data);

}
```

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder how can i set TypeDesc.text for each item in the class presently its setting the first value for all the TypeDesc

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the lable a unique ID like `id="TypeDesc{i}"` or something different.

So you can refer to it something like this:
`$('#TypeDesc{i}').text = data.responseText;`